# ModuleNotFoundError after installing Pillow

Tags: python, django, modulenotfounderror

The HTTP is giving me the ModuleNotFoundError whichever link I go.

The ModuleNotFoundError is giving me the following information:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /web/

No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/web/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'django.core.context_processors'
Exception Location: <frozen importlib._bootstrap>, line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Python Executable:  /Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/wfw_fixed/env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/wfw_fixed/wfw',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/william/Documents/coding/WDTP/wfw_fixed/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 23 Jan 2021 00:07:14 +0000
```

It is happening since I installed Pillow.

In my `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for wfw project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os.path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Test for settings templates path
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'wfw_editor.apps.WfwEditorConfig',
    'feedback.apps.FeedbackConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wfw.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'django.core.context_processors.tz',
                'django.core.context_processors',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I don't think I need the below part, but I posted it anyway:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wfw.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I removed the SECRET_KEY variable.
Is the problem occurring in the `settings.py`?
Is the problem because I didn't import something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to import `django.template.context_processors.*` instead of:

```
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.core.context_processors',
```

Because, looking inside `django.core`, seems like there's no module named `context_processors`:

````
>>> dir(django.template.context_processors)
['SimpleLazyObject', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'csrf', 'debug', 'get_token', 'i18n', 'itertools', 'lazy', 'media', 'request', 'settings', 'static', 'tz']
>>> dir(django.core)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'cache', 'checks', 'exceptions', 'files', 'mail', 'management', 'paginator', 'serializers', 'signals', 'signing', 'validators']```
````

Comment: ['django.template.context_processors'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/template/context_processors/) is a module, and now it's raising me a TypeError at /admin/login/: 'module' object is not callable.